# Blank screen when running cinnamon and cairo dock

Tags: gnome, cinnamon, cairo-dock

Here is the problem that I am haveing. When I log in using Gnome w/ cairo dock I get a blank screen and a mouse cursor. I can not right click or anything. I hit alt f2 and it brings up the tty term. I try to issue cinnamon or compiz or any other manager and it just says that x has no display or something similar. I then have to issue sudo service mdm restart and it brings me back to the login screen.

Then I can login to cinnamon with cairo dock running with no problem. Any help would be appreciated.. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those commands only work when you are in an xsession and not on a text only session like tty2. You can, however, issue kill commands from there like

```
sudo killall cairo-dock
```

and you can restart the xsession by killing lightdm gdm or what ever dm you are using like this

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

or

```
sudo service gdm restart
```

Alternatively, if the dm is the culprit you can start x with no dm like this

```
sudo service lightdm stop
sudo startx
```

replacing lightdm with your dm.

Finally, you can start those commands that did not work due to no display but you have to specify the display for them to open. I'm not exactly sure how to do this but it's something like display=0:0.

Comment: The following did help,startx did start the xorg environment. However the sound was not present when I started the xorg environment. I am still looking for a fix for it, but at least I can get it to sart. I am going to keep looking for a fix and if I find one I will post back with an answer.